# Automatic URL rewrite after deleting a product

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting, magento-1.7, http-status-code-301

Is there any way in magento to make an automatic url rewrite to the category of the product, after deleting that product?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Catalog URL Rewrites Index Process to "Update on Save".

Check screenshot: http://prnt.sc/cdmoco

Comment: I cannot find this setting in my magento site, where can I find this?

Comment: Go to System->Index Management

Select all and do as this: http://prntscr.com/cfj52e

Select this option and click on save: http://prntscr.com/cfj59h

Comment: Nothing major will change if I do this? This wil make an automatic redirect to the category page when I delete a product?

Comment: This will still give an 404 page of the deleted product.